# Frombinding on null object: RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm continuing my learning for Play 2.0 and I'm working on a **Login form**. Basically the similar form as the sample project Zentasks provide...

My problem is the error message when no user could be found in the database, the error occurs on the following line:

```
Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
```

My Model looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

@Constraints.Required
public String password;

@Constraints.Required
public String email;

// -- Queries

public static Model.Finder<String, Person> find = new Model.Finder(String.class, Person.class);

/**
 * Authenticate a User.
 */
public static Person authenticate(String email, String password) {
Logger.info("email: " + email + " and password is:" + password);
    return find.where().eq("email", email).eq("password", password).findUnique();
}

/**
 * Retrieve all users.
 */
public static List<Person> findAll() {
return find.all();
}

// --

}
```

And my controller looks like:

```
/**
 * Handle login form submission.
 */
public static Result authenticate() {
play.Logger.info("Entering authenticated method...");

Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE

if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.login.render(loginForm));
} else {
    session("email", loginForm.get().email);
    return redirect(routes.LandingPage.index());
}
}
```

And my Login class inside the Application.java:

```
public static class Login {

public String email;
public String password;

public String validate() {
    Logger.info("Entering validation in class login... " + email + "   " + password);
    if (Person.authenticate(email, password) == null) {
    return "Invalid user or password";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

BTW, I use mySql as my database. And I have a valid user the code is working just fine...

**UPDATE 17-04-2012**

If you ever run into strange thing in Play2.0 just debug it carefully. I come from PHP and I tried debugging with sysouts! But that is not ok. Run **play debug run** and hit F6 untill you know where it goes wrong!

In my case I was Logging something that was not saved yet in the database, in fact it did not exist yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a typo (the **static** part)?

```
public static class Login {
}
```

If not that may be the reason. AFAIK the Form classes must be POJOs.

Comment: If I remove the keyword static I get the compilation error: type Login is not a member of object controllers.Application. BTW: the static is also as mentioned in the zentask sample project...

Comment: Just as a trial, can you move the class out of the Applications class, into its own file, as a public class, and try again? Remember to update the imports.

Comment: Hi Pierre, with the Login.class seperate it still did not worked. It works when I used one of my Model classes, a basic Person class.. I do not understand this behaviour...

Comment: Hi Adis, I'm afaid there may be extra reasons. Please check the computer-database project at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database-jpa and compare with your code.

Comment: YES! Thank you, since I do not have any user in the database I still tried to Log the users id, and the error occured on this line, so removing the Log statement, and now it works :-) Thanks Pierre!

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem but I don't understand the solution.